# Change state for each button individually

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a button to show details of each card in my react project like this. the amount of cards are unknown and it is based on what I get from API.

just like this, I get the data and I'm mapping it:

```
 <div className={styles.contentCardContainer}>
        {factorList !== undefined && factorList.length > 0 ? (
          factorList.map((list, i) => (
            <div key={uuidv4()} className={styles.contentCard}>
              <IconButton
                color={showListService ? "error" : "success"}
                onClick={() => {
                  setShowlistService((prev) => !prev);
                  HandleFetchDetails(list.ID);
                }}
                sx={{
                  display: "flex",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  alignSelf: "flex-start",
                }}
              >
                {showListService ? <RemoveCircle /> : <AddCircle />}
              </IconButton>
              <section className={styles.eachSection}>
                <img src={doctorImage} alt="doctor" />
                <p>{list.Doctor}</p>
              </section>
              <section className={styles.eachSection}>
                <img src={calendarImage} alt="doctor" />
                <p>
                  {list.Date}   
                  {list.Time}
                </p>
              </section>
              <section className={styles.eachSection}>
                <img src={RialImage} alt="doctor" />
                <p>{list.Payable}  ریال</p>
              </section>
              <section className={styles.eachSection}>
                <img src={discountImage} alt="doctor" />
                <p>{list.discount}</p>
              </section>
              {showListService && (
                <DetailsListService listDetails={listDetails} styles={styles} />
              )}
            </div>
          ))
        ) : (
          <Alert
            variant="filled"
            severity="warning"
            sx={{ justifyContent: "space-between" }}
          >
            <p>There's no data</p>
          </Alert>
        )}
      </div>
</div>
```

as you can see, I have `IconButton` element that I mapped it so each element have this button. but there's a problem.
I just have one state.

just like this :

```
  const [showListService, setShowlistService] = React.useState(false);
```

since the amount cards I will receive is unknown. I can't define multiple states, because I don't know how many I should define. this is a bad practice too.

so whenever I click on `IconButton`, state changes for ALL buttons. how can I make it work individually.

change state for just a button in that specific element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a component for the cards and each card can keep the state:

```js
factorList.map((factor, index) => {
  return <Card key={index} factor={factor} />;
});

const Card = ({ factor }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);

  return <div>Your card stuff here</div>;
};
```